# What would be webdriver equivalent for assertconfirmation?

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver, junit4

What would be the Webdriver equivalent for **assertconfirmation** ?
I have following selenium IDE code which when exported to JUnit 4 (Webdriver) returns an error:

IDE code:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Logout</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertConfirmation</td>
    <td>Are you sure you want to logout?</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Exported Webdriver code which corresponds to above:

```
@Test
    public void testUntitled2() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
        // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [getConfirmation]]
    }
```

I use to be able to successfully use the following with RC but with webdriver it no longer works - (please note I am trying to migrate my scripts to webdriver)

```
assertTrue(selenium.getConfirmation().matches("^Are you sure you want to logout[\\s\\S]$"));
```

Cheers

Shan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be it!

```
final String text = "Are you sure you want to logout?";
assertTrue(driver.switchTo().alert().getText().equals(text));
```

...or maybe the 'matches()' version you got there.

[switchTo()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo%28%29)

[alert()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#alert%28%29)

[getText()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#getText%28%29)